# How do I to findViewByTag?

Tags: android

Say I have dynamically generated some amount of LinearLayout, all with different tags.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
{
        final LinearLayout LinLayBtn = new LinearLayout(this);
        LinLayBtn.setTag( "id"+String.valueOf(i) );
         ...
```

And now I need to somehow access this layout by they tag number from a different method.

```
LinearLayout LinLayBtn = (LinearLayout)findViewWithTag("1");
```

What would be the best way to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: i would preffer to prefix tags with letters, don't know if `number only tag identificator` isn't wrong at all...

Comment: done. :) but still, how should I access it later on?

Comment: If you created the Views why do you need to find them, you know them already.

Comment: I have dynamically created them with a for-loop in one function. but now I need to change something to one of them from another, therefor I need some way to access it.

Comment: Why not getting them throw the component they laid on it? something like `parent.getChild(i)`

Comment: They might be in different orders and there might be more parents. Aren't there any way to get them by Tag?

Comment: store the LinearLayouts in a List? and then iterate over them to find the match, still u will need a tag. Runtime optimization.

Comment: Yes, sound like an idea! Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Have you tried it this way and found a problem with it?

You'll need to make this line

```
LinearLayout LinLayBtn = (LinearLayout)findViewWithTag("1");
```

match the naming scheme you used when you set the tag. So you'd want something like this in your example:

```
LinearLayout LinLayBtn = (LinearLayout)findViewWithTag("id1");
```

If you need to do many of these lookups though it would probably be a better approach to store the view references in an array while you are creating them so you don't have to have all of the findView calls. Or do like @Muhammad suggested and use parent.getChild(index i);

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#findViewWithTag%28java.lang.Object%29  findViewWithTag() is a real method of the View class...