# How to use Android view element by tag

Tags: android, layout, textview

I have some TextView elements in my layout file like below:

```
<Table Layout>
    ...

    <TableRow android:gravity="center_horizontal">    
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv1"
            android:text="@string/text_value"
            android:tag="id1">

     ...

    <TableRow android:gravity="center_horizontal">    
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv1"
            android:text="@string/text_value"
            android:tag="idN">

     ...

</TableLayout>
```

I want to use

```
  for (int i=0; i < 10; i++) {
     myText = (TextView) findViewbyTag("id"+i);
     myText.setText("id is - "+i);
  }
```

construction to match each tag value and set text value into each TextView element.
It doesn't work!
I understand how tp use it by id, but id is int value from resources and I can't 
generate it in my for() construction.

What can I do? How do I use findViewbyTag?

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7455897/how-do-i-to-findviewbytag)

Comment: What did you mean by "it doesn't work"? App crashed? Nothing happened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use tags. You should rather use dynamical resource retrieval as following.

```
for (int i=0; i < 10; i++) {
  // generate id dynamically
  int id = getResources().getIdentifier("tv"+i, "id", getPackageName());
  // find view by generated id
  TextView myText = (TextView) findViewbyId(id);
  myText.setText("id is - tv"+i);
}
```

The both `getResources()` and `getPackageName()` are the methods of `Context`.